# How to use the multiprocessing module on python to execute a spatial join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, spatial-analyst, spatial-join, parallel-processing

I have several shapefiles of the entire Amazon rainforest each with millions of polygons (they are fairly detailed and take some time to draw on ArcMap). I need each of these shapefiles to be spatially joined with another shapefile called landuseA (which, itself, is a very big file). Given how computer intensive this task is, I would like to use the multiprocessing module on python to improve performance. How do I do this?

I have read the blog post by Esri on the multiprocessing module, but I cannot figure out how I can use their example to write a script that will use multiple processors to execute a spatial join. Blog post is here: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/26/distributed-processing-with-arcgis-part-1/

If you have other suggestions for how this task might be better accomplished, feel free to share that too.

Comment: If the shapefiles are large, you should be using file geodatabase to prevent hitting file size limits. You should edit the question to contain a link to the referenced blog.

Comment: Thanks Vince. All the data are stored in a file geodatabase

Comment: So do you have "several shapefiles" or "several FGDB feature classes"? It changes the problem significantly.

Comment: I have several FGDB feature classes. I apologize for my misuse of  gis argot. The data were initially in shapefile format and were imported into a feature dataset stored in a file geodatabase.

Comment: multiprocessing or multithreading? take some time to familiarize yourself with the difference between those two and I believe the answer will come

Comment: You *can't* use several processes to execute a spatial join, since the implication on a join is that it's to be used by a single process.  You *can* use one process to partition the dataset into working subfolders, then use multiprocessing to run UNION operations in the subfolders, then once the jobs are complete merge the result. 90% of the work of using multiprocessing is balancing the load so that the effort of organization gains you more time than just letting a job run overnight or over a weekend.

Comment: thanks Vince. This is very helpful. Any reason why you suggested a union instead of a spatial join? I should add that I'm joining each feature class to the feature class landuseA because I want each of them to have an ID which I can use to join them all together in one big table

Comment: With no answer in nearly a year I think you should [edit] your question to incorporate your learnings from comments and re-clarify what it is that you want to ask now.